# Social Engine: How to write PHP code in HTML Block?

Tags: socialengine

I have created a new page using Layout Editor. I found the options to add the HTML codes using HTML Block. I would like to add PHP code in that HTML block section. How can I do? Please advice me. I spend more than 2 hours for the solution. But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cant include PHP code into HTML blocks
Try this widget [I4US PHP Block](http://www.socialengine.com/customize/se4/mod-page?mod_id=472): from integration4us.com (site closed?) This is old plugin, but still best solution for you request, using it on my 2 SE4 sites.

This widget was absolutely free, you can download it [here](http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/44751226/file.html).